# Pivot longer with sets of columns

Tags: r, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a huge dataset with large number of variables (parameters) for 32 individuals. Its a wide dataset with columns ranging from for example first names for all the individuals, last names for all the individuals, roles, institutions and other parameters. All variables start with the same prefix for example `college_collaborator` and new variables start with  `_` and then a numeric value ranging from 1 to 32, then names of individual parameters separated by underscores. Examples would be `college_collaborator_1_First_name, college_collaborator_2_First_name, college_collaborator_3_First_name` and example of 2nd set of variables would be `college_collaborator_1_last_name, college_collaborator_2_last_name, college_collaborator_3_last_name`. I have 32 numbers of each of these parameters.

The dataset would look something like this:
dataset_1

```
dataset_1 <- read.table(text=
"ID     cb_1_fn  cb_2_fn cb_3_fn cb_1_ln cb_2_ln cb_3_ln
1      Jill       Pete    Edy     James    Lil    febe
2      Aliya      Edy     Jill    Troy     adam   tom
3      Tom        John    Moss    Pete     Fun    Tom
4      Phill      Sam     Kale    Jack     Dallas lil
5      Tim        David   Sam     Dale     Simmon Fig", header=TRUE)
```

What is the best way to use `pivot_longer` to tidy a large set of columns to collapse them into smaller sets at the same time using variable names with similar prefixes (as mentioned above)? For instant have all the first names in the same column and the last names in the same but different column and so on and so forth. Output dataset would look something as follows:

```
Status      fn          ln

cb_1       Jill        James
cb_1       Aliya       Troy 
cb_1       Tom         Pete 
cb_1       Phill       Jack
cb_1       Tim         Dale
cb_2       Pete        Lil
cb_2       Edy         Adam
cb_2       John        Son
cb_2       Sam         Dallas
cb_2       David       Simmon
cb_3       Edy         Febe
cb_3       Jill        tom
cb_3       Moss        Tom
cb_3       Kale        Lil
cb_3       Sam         Fig
```

My struggle is to not just separate the names but also to collapse certain set of variables under individual columns.

Comment: Use the `".value"` sentinel with `names_pattern`: `df %>% pivot_longer(!ID, names_to = c("Status", ".value"), names_pattern = "(cb_\\d)_(.+)")`.

Comment: @zephryl this worked perfectly. Can you please explain the regex part? It looks like the first capturing group is putting the prefix part to status and the 2nd capturing group is providing names for individual values. Thanks

Comment: Right -- in conjunction with the argument `names_to = c("Status", ".value")`, this tells R to apply the pattern to the select column names, pivot all unique results of the first capture group to separate rows (with the matched pattern as values in a column named `Status`), but to retain all unique results of the second capture group as columns (with the matched patterns as names). If that's just confused things more, maybe the `names_to`, `names_pattern`, and Examples sections of [`?pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) will help.